# Cannot select multiple file after first successful upload in filefield extjs

Tags: extjs

On first render of this form, I can select multiple files and successfully uploaded them to server. Upon second attempt or more to browse another files to upload, upload dialog window restricts to one file only. Please help. Still new to extjs. Here is the code. Thank you.

```
    Ext.onReady(function () {

        Ext.QuickTips.init();
        Ext.form.Field.prototype.msgTarget = 'side';

        formUpload.render(document.body);
    });

    var formUpload = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {

        labelWidth      : 85,
        frame           : true,
        title           : 'Login user',
        width           : 460,
        defaults        : {width: 250, allowBlank: false},
        defaultType     : 'textfield',
        url             : 'php/uploadimage.php',
        style: {
            marginLeft  : 'auto',
            marginRight : 'auto'
        },

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'filefield',
                name: 'images[]',
                fieldLabel: 'Name',
                emptyText: 'Select images',
                margin: '20',
                anchor: '95%',
                buttonText: 'Browse',
                buttonConfig: {
                    iconCls: 'upload-icon'
                },
                style: {
                    marginLeft  : 'auto',
                    marginRight : 'auto'
                },
                listeners : {
                    afterrender : function(cmp){
                        cmp.fileInputEl.set({
                            multiple: 'multiple'
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        buttons: [
            {
                text        : 'submit',
                formBind    : true,
                disabled    : true,
                handler     : function(){

                    if(formUpload.isValid())
                    {
                        formUpload.submit({
                            success     : function(form, action){

                                var assoc = Ext.JSON.decode(action.response.responseText);
                                Ext.MessageBox.alert('Succeeded', assoc["reason"]);
                            },
                            failure     : function(form, action){

                                var assoc = Ext.JSON.decode(action.response.responseText);
                                Ext.MessageBox.alert('Failed', assoc["reason"]);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        ]

    });
```

EDIT:

It works after setting the filefield to multiple again.

```
formUpload.submit({
    success     : function(form, action){

        Ext.getCmp('picfield').fileInputEl.set({multiple: true});   //  set fileuploadfield to multiple
        var assoc = Ext.JSON.decode(action.response.responseText);
        Ext.MessageBox.alert('Succeeded', assoc["reason"]);
    },
    failure     : function(form, action){

        Ext.getCmp('picfield').fileInputEl.set({multiple: true});   //  set fileuploadfield to multiple
        var assoc = Ext.JSON.decode(action.response.responseText);
        Ext.MessageBox.alert('Failed', assoc["reason"]);
    }
});
```

I just append "Ext.getCmp('picfield').fileInputEl.set({multiple: true});" inside  success and failure function body. Still need an explanation what fileInputEl is all about.